# ContentPresenter.ContentSource vs Content

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate, contentpresenter

Basically, I don't understand what the real difference here is:

The Microsoft code for TabItem uses:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" ... />
```

So, when would one use the `Content` property instead of (or in addition to) `ContentSource`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> This property should only be used when
>   the ContentPresenter is in a template.
>   When a template contains a
>   ContentPresenter with ContentSource
>   set to "Abc", the Content,
>   ContentTemplate, and
>   ContentTemplateSelector properties of
>   the ContentPresenter are automatically
>   aliased to Abc, AbcTemplate, and
>   AbcTemplateSelector, respectively.
>   Beginning with the .NET Framework
>   version 3.5 Service Pack 1, setting
>   ContentSource to "Abc" also causes the
>   ContentStringFormat property to be
>   aliased to AbcStringFormat.
>
> The two most useful values for this
>   property are "Content" and "Header".

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.contentsource.aspx))

`ContentSource` apparently sets more properties at once for convenience.

---

Practically, The declaration:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
```

Performs the following initialization.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                  ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                  ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" />
```

It does this for each property separately only if the dependency property exists on the templated control.

Comment: Man, this explains so much (that the docs don't!) I always wondered why just having a `ContentPresenter` in a template without setting `Content` still worked.  Now I know it's because it *does* set `Content`, just implicitly from this property (along with the others as well.)  They really should update the docs because it's not clear that by 'aliased' they really mean the equivalent of using a `TemplateBinding`. Had they stated that or even mentioned `TemplateBinding`, it would've been so much clearer. Your code example does so perfectly. Bravo!